# How do i add more text field to this code so it could connect to the email and so it could be sent

Tags: ios, email

I need help how do add more textfield name to this code so all info from textfield goes to the email composer thing.

```
NSString *message = [[self Name]text];
```

Comment: What do you mean by adding more textFields, which textfields to you need to add?, I have the code right here for sending this as an email, but I don't quite understand what you are looking for exactly

Comment: I have a lot of textfield and all i want is connect all my textfields to that one line of code so all the info from the textfield goes straight to the email composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have many TextFields and you want to add all text inside them to one NSString you could do the following :

```
NSMutableString * string = [NSMutableString new] ;
[string appendString:textField1.text] ; 
[string appendString:textField2.text] ; 
[string appendString:textField3.text] ;
```

where textField1 , textField2 are your textFields

Answer (score 0):

here's how you can do this: 
1. concatenate strings:

```
NSString * a1;
NSString * a2;
NSString * a3;

NSString * emailString = [a1 stringByAppendingString:[@", " stringByAppendingString:[a2 stringByAppendingString:[@", " stringByAppendingString:a3]]]];
```

Method for sending emails:

```
-(void)sendEmail:(NSString*)emailBody emailSubject:(NSString*)emailSubject {
    MFMailComposeViewController* composerViewController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [composerViewController setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    [composerViewController setSubject:emailSubject];
    [composerViewController setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:FALSE];
    [self presentViewController:composerViewController animated:TRUE completion:nil];
}
```

call the following method like so:

```
[self sendEmail:emailString emailSubject:@"some subject"];
```

Make sure you declare your delegates:

```
@interface SOMEViewController () <MFMessageComposeViewControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
@end
```

Placing everything into one shot would be this with email, password, and name textFields:

```
NSString * emailString = [_emailField.text stringByAppendingString:[@", " stringByAppendingString:[_nameField.text stringByAppendingString:[@", " stringByAppendingString:_passwordField.text]]]];
```

I should say, that this method of concatenation will output the following:

> ```
> "email", "name", "password"
> ```